# How long does a static member of a controller stay alive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I have a controller in ASP.NET like this:

```
 public class FileUploadController : Controller
 { 
    // ...
    static List<ThreePartKey> uploadedFiles = new List<ThreePartKey> ();
    // ... 

    public ActionResult Index ( )
    {
       // ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index (HttpPostedFileBase file, 
                               string selectedOrgName, 
                               string selectedCatName)
    {
        // ...
        uploadedFiles.Add(new ThreePartKey { 
             orgname = selectedOrgName, 
             catname = selectedCatName, 
             filename = fileNameNoExtension });

        ViewBag.uploadedFiles = uploadedFiles;
        return View();
    }
 }
```

where the second `Index` function uploads a file that the user chooses and adds its information to a list of uploaded files.  That list information is used to build out an HTML table. The reason I ended up prefixing `List<ThreePartKey> uploadedFiles` with `static` is because without it my list would only have the last uploaded file each time I invoked `Index`.

How long does that list stay in memory?  I was hoping for it to correspond to user `sessions`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It should be there until IIS recycles or until it reloads the app domain. It's static so it will never be cleaned up by the garbage collector during normal  operation if I understand statics correctly in those terms.

Comment: `static` means there will only be one instance per application. In IIS, this means one instance per AppPool. This is a problem if you're trying to store per-user information. Why don't you just use `Session`?

Answer (score 5):

Static variables are global to an AppDomain and last the life of the AppDomain. The value wouldn't be user-specific and would basically stick around until the web app restarts in the case of ASP.NET.

It's also worth noting that static variables aren't necessarily thread safe, so care should be taken when manipulating the variable. In your case, the List<ThreePartKey> is NOT inherently thread safe, so you should accommodate for that in your code (unless you change the implementation to use a session variable or something).

Comment: Please clarify that this is not unique to ASP.NET, that this is how static variables work throughout .NET.